# OData services don't return the default order in which the items are present in the db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using OData services for my Web Api to provide pagination to my client app. This is the code for one of my controller methods.

```
// Get all Categories
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("all")]
    public ODataResult<DataAccess.Model.Category> GetCategoryList(ODataQueryOptions options)
    {          

        var categoryList = this.Repository.GetCategories().AsQueryable<Category>();

        var results = (options.ApplyTo(categoryList) as IQueryable<DataAccess.Model.Category>);                     


        long count = categoryList.Count();

        if (count == 0) 
            count = 1; // throws up an ArgumentException error if the count is less than 1

        return new ODataResult<DataAccess.Model.Category>(results, null, count);

    }
```

But when i use any OData protocols in the api call like api/Category/all?$skip&$top=5 it doesnt return me the exact order in which the  5-10 elements are there in the db (i.e sorted by their primary key=ID). I can fix this by using $orderby=ID for all my API calls, but i want to know if i can avoid it. Am i doing anything wrong here because by default the OData services should return in the same order as they are in the db right? Please let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By default, we sort the result set by the key property to make sure that there is a stable sort (if not pagination would be broken). So, It would be interesting to see what your model is i.e how DataAccess.Model.Category looks like. 
Also, if you want to do the stable sort yourself and disable the webapi inferred order, you can use ODataQuerySettings.EnsureStableOrdering (false) to the other overload of ApplyTo i.e

```
public virtual IQueryable ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in OData forces a specific ordering unless the client asked for it.
The $top and $skip query options force "some stable" ordering which by default (in the .NET implementation) uses the ordering on key properties (primary key), but if you simply ask for all entities in a set, the service will not force any ordering (as it doesn't need to) and thus will return whatever order the underlying provider gives (depends on the DB and so on).

Comment: When am calling for all entities it is giving an ordered list based on the primary key but when am using skip and top it isnt. Thats whatz bothering me!! Even when i use skip and top it should still sort on the primary key right?

Comment: OK - I didn't understand that... yes - I would expect sort by primary key for $top and $skip as well. I don't know why it's not happening for you.

Comment: In my situation, it's forcing order by the primary key for me when I use the OData `$top` keyword (and it's ignoring my `.OrderBy` LINQ clause!). :-/